# userid value is not increasing in user_id column

Tags: jdbc

I am using user_id column in my table and keep it incrementing by 1 each time a  new user is registered. but after U10, useId is **not increasing** and after this  each new user  have userId U10. I am using MySql please suggest how to resolve this, or any other way to achieve this.

below is my code for generating **userId**

```
               public int addUser(UserTO uto){
         int status=0;
         PreparedStatement ps1=null;
           PreparedStatement ps2=null;
            PreparedStatement ps3=null;
          Connection con=DBUtil.getMySqlConnection(); 
            String new_user_id=null;    
try{
     ps1=con.prepareStatement("select user_id from users order by user_id");   
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();   
    if(rs1.last()){
    int id=Integer.parseInt((rs1.getString(1).substring(1)));
    new_user_id="U"+(id+1);
          }
  else{

        new_user_id="U1";

    }
     uto.setUserid(new_user_id);


      ps3=con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     ps3.setString(1,uto.getUserid());
     ps3.setString(2,uto.getType());
     ps3.setString(3,uto.getUsername());
     ps3.setString(4,uto.getPassword());
     ps3.setString(5,uto.getFirstname());
     ps3.setString(6,uto.getMiddlename());
     ps3.setString(7,uto.getLastname());
     ps3.setString(8,uto.getPhone());
     ps3.setString(9,uto.getFax());
     ps3.setString(10,uto.getEmail());
     ps3.setString(11,uto.getJobtitle());
     ps3.setString(12,uto.getDepartment());
     ps3.setString(13,uto.getCompanyname());
     ps3.setString(14,uto.getLocation());
     ps3.setString(15,uto.getGender());
     ps3.setString(16,uto.getClientid());

     status=ps3.executeUpdate();         

   }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
         DBUtil.cleanup(ps1,con);
         DBUtil.cleanup(ps2,con);
         DBUtil.cleanup(ps3,con);
   }
return status;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have something to do with the fact that you are adding an integer to a string in this line but I'm not sure, I don't know much about java:

```
new_user_id="U"+(id+1);
```

However, you could skip the first query and generate the user_id within the INSERT query that follows, all with SQL. Something like

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(CONCAT("U", IFNULL(MAX((SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(user_id, 2) AS UNSIGNED) FROM users)), 0) + 1), ?, ?, ?....
```

If you do that you should remove the first parameter you're binding for that query.

I'm not gonna ask why you aren't using an AUTO_INCREMENT for the user primary id.